# Excel: formula to identify missing sku

Tags: excel, excel-formula, inventory, inventory-management, sku

I have a list of 1500 sku. Currently we have an active inventory of 450 sku. 
I am looking for an excel formula that will identify when the sku inputed is not an active sku of the 450.

I have tried various `IF` functions, but having a hard time breaking it down.

I have tried this:

```
=IF($B2=F1:F460, COUNTIF(PRODUCTION!$A$1:$AJ$45, $d2), "")
```

The first part of the equation is where we input the inventory. `F1:f460` is a list of all the active sku. The second part of the code is where it goes to look for the code if it on the production sheet.

I need to know when we put a sku into the inventory if it is correct or not.

Comment: What are `$B2` and `$D2`?  I feel like the formula should be looking for the same sku in both locations, so why are there different cell references?

Comment: VLOOKUP is your friend

Comment: hey tigeravatar! $b2 is where the "bad sku" is inputted. $d2 is where the formula is located to see if the sku entered in b2 is inactive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(SkuToTest=F1:F460))>0
```

The logic behind this is explained [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-equals-one-of-many-things).  If you want to show only skus that are not in your list, you can wrap it in an `IF` like so:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(SkuToTest=F1:F460))>0,"","FALSE")
```

Comment: This totally worked! Thank you so much! Is there a way with this code to only return when it is false?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean to show a blank if the sku matches and `FALSE` if it does not.  I edited my answer to show how to do that.  Also, please accept this answer if it does indeed answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
=isnumber(Match(SKUYouWantToTest,450SKURange,0))
```

The match returns a number if the SKU is in the list, and an error otherwise. The isnumber converts it to a TRUE if it exists, and a FALSE otherwise