# Matching similar but different SKU codes in excel

Tags: excel, match

We have done the stock count which resulted in some items (code in our ERP) not found, but a similar code with minor deviations has been identified as excess stock. See the example below. Which function can I use to be able to find those matches? This is just one of the examples, the other deviations include replacement of characters, extra spaces, etc...

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4kTn.png)

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbKYx.png)

Comment: Why not remove extra spaces first with substitute() or trim() then re-check.

Comment: You could just include some actual examples as text in your post - easier than having to view two separate images...  Anyhow - maybe try this out:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel: formula to identify missing sku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55814609/excel-formula-to-identify-missing-sku)

Comment: Tim, thank you, I have tried it just now and it seems to work well. thank you! Mike, I have done the trimming before but the data is so raw that it is super difficult to do.